# Proof of exponentiation rules

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Is there a source where I can find the proofs of all the power rules
i.e. $a^r \cdot a^s=a^{r+s}$ etc for

(i)  $ r,s \in \mathbb{N}$

(ii)  $ r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$

(iii)  $ r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$

(iv)  $ r,s \in \mathbb{R}$

(v)  $ r,s \in \mathbb{C}$

Any link, book or anything?

Comment: see here http://andrusia.com/math/preliminaries/ExponentiationTheorems.pdf i hope this will help you

Comment: Hint: How do you **define** exponentiation for $a^r$ when $r\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: I remember [this](https://www.amazon.com/Number-System-Meigs-Hubbell-Olmsted/dp/1258426927) book have.

Comment: Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis have a great exercise in the first chapter that leads to this result. To be specific, I'm talking about exercise 6 on the first chapter. If you have access to the book you should check it, otherwise, I can explain the process in an answer format.

Comment: I have the book at home. Is this excercise solved?